# Cryptography using groups

Tags: group-theory, cryptography, primality-test

For my math essay I decided to explore the use of group theory in cryptography; as opposed to looking at the coding algorithms I'd like to look more at the math behind it, assuming I know the basis of abelian groups and just group theory in general, can someone please point me to some resources on the matter that go through the math? After a few days of searching I haven't found much in the terms of actual math involved. I think I should be looking along the the lines of groups of prime numbers in combination with primality test operations right?

Comment: in a first place, you have to look at how RSA is built, then the algorithms based on the discrete logarithm, and then on elliptic curves. I think it is mostly a matter of asymmetric encryption , symmetric encryption being much less based on groups than on XOR and bit sequence generation from a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent book in the cryptography called "An introduction to mathematical cryptography" that you can see it's content in this link:

https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/MathCryptoHome.html

Chapter six of this book is about "Lattices and Cryptography". In the chapter six, there is a part called "The NTRU Public Key Cryptosystem ". In this part you can see the role of Algebra specially the ring subject to construction of  public key in the cryptography.